# Changing log path in postgresql

Tags: postgresql, path, logfile

I have a problem with setting log path in postgresql. My postgres runs on Windows Server. I want to change a path and set new path on network disk. I mapped network drive and set it in postgresql.conf.

```
log_directory = 'Z:\\temp' (or log_directory = 'Z:/temp')
```

After restart postgres, windows shows
[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NP5Gw.png)

I add all privileges to shared folder.

Comment: Try starting the server manually with something like `postgres.exe -D "D:\path\to\data_dir"` (replace with the directory where `postgresql.conf` is) and look at the error message.

Comment: Maybe the network drive is mapped just for you, not for the user running PG. Try to use the full UNC path ( `\\server\path\to\temp`)